# Twilio Get Most Recent Message with PHP

Tags: php, twilio

I'm trying to get the last message received on a channel, I am using the "[Programmable Chat > Programmable Chat REST API > Messages Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/messages)", this is my actual code:

```
$messages = $client->chat
                   ->services($serviceId)
                   ->channels($channel["channelSID"])
                   ->messages
                   ->read();

$lastMessage = end($messages);
```

But it is fairly slow, is there a way to limit the query in PHP?

In Javascript I would do something like:

```
channel.getMessages(1).then(function(messages) {
    // code
});
```

Comment: If you are using V2 of messaging, it looks like it can take both a limit and a page parameter. https://twilio.github.io/twilio-php/5.13.2/class-Twilio.Rest.Chat.V2.Service.Channel.MessageList.html

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can limit the query in the [Twilio PHP library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php) by passing the [`$limit` argument to the `read` method](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-php/5.13.2/source-class-Twilio.Rest.Chat.V2.Service.Channel.MessageList.html#112). Like this:

```
$messages = $client->chat
                   ->services($serviceId)
                   ->channels($channel["channelSID"])
                   ->messages
                   ->read(array(), 1);

$lastMessage = end($messages);
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks you, let me try.